# Have dependent fields default to a value based on controlling field

Tags: force.com

i have a picklist, and when the user selects a value, i want other picklists on the object to default to another value.

I tried field dependencies, but that defaults to the default value of the field (which in this case is --None--)

Comment: I assume you are trying to do this natively?  You are going to have to use VF and Apex for this.  Do you have VF experience?

Comment: this is going to a page that changes all the time- so i don't want to do VF. i'd prefer to stay native

Comment: This isnt something you can accomplish natively.  Workflows and trigger will only work with DML operations, so I really don't think you can make have the picklist values conditional in the standard UI.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: you're right about workflows and triggers... Any other way i can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in standard layout or via any customization. The only thing we can do is keep voting for [Enable Default Picklist Values on Dependent Picklists](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br9GAAS) idea.

Answer (score 1):

Dependent picklists are the only way that you can accomplish this declaratively and with the native UI. Visualforce is currently the only way to surface custom UI, aside from a canvas app (which doesn't really apply to this use case).